# TypeError: Update_Profile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, django, django-users

Whenever I am creating the superuser then it's throwing me an error 
`Update_Profile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.`

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def Update_Profile(self, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.user_profile.save()
```

Comment: `Update_Profile` expects to be called within an object instance, i.e. `profile.Update_Profile()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be, (without `self`)

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def Update_Profile(instance, created, **kwargs):
...
```

Comment: yes i made a little mistake, thank you so much for guide me :)

Comment: and, one more thing, it's nice to write python function names in *"snake_case"* so your function name will become, ***`update_profile(....)`***